# Override Block & Template File in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, template, sales-order, override-block

What is the best way to override the below files theme/module & how one can override it ?

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Items/Grid.php


app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/items/grid.phtml
```

Comment: Any thoughts how to override the above files ?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is that, you can override this into the Magento extension.

So when you enable/disable that things, that will work with this extension.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer sir.